# How can I fix this "OutOfBoundaryException" error?

Tags: java, class, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class DataInput {
String name[];
int korean[], math[], english[];
int sum[];
double average[];
int students;
int rank[];

public void save() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in number of students");
    students = sc.nextInt();

    name = new String[students];
    korean = new int[students];
    math = new int[students];
    english = new int[students];
    sum = new int[students];
    average = new double[students];
    rank = new int[students];

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        System.out.println("Type name");
        name[i] = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Type Korean score");
        korean[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type math score");
        math[i] = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type English score");
        english[i] = sc.nextInt();

        sum[i] = korean[i] + math[i] + english[i];
        average[i] = sum[i] / 3.0;

    }

}

int stu() {
    return students;
}

int[] sum() {
    return sum;
}

}

class DataOutput {
DataInput data = new DataInput();
int sNum;
int[] rrank, sum;

DataOutput(int students, int[] sum) {
    this.sNum = students;
    this.rrank = new int[sNum];
    this.sum = sum;
}

void ranker() {

    int cnt = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sNum; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sNum; j++) {
            if (sum[i] < sum[j]) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        rrank[i] = cnt;
        cnt = 1;
    }

}
}

public class Score {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DataInput data = new DataInput();
    int sNum = data.stu();
    int[] sum = data.sum();
    DataOutput out = new DataOutput(sNum, sum);
    data.save();
    out.ranker();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Name\t\tKorean  math  English \t sum  Average  Rank");
    System.out
            .println("-------------------------------------------------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < data.stu(); i++) {
        System.out.println(data.name[i] + "\t\t" + data.korean[i] + "  "
                + data.math[i] + "  " + data.english[i] + "\t"
                + data.sum[i] + "  " + data.average[i] + "  "
            + out.rrank[i]); // this is where i get an Exception
    }

}

}
```

So, this is my program for getting ranks of students. But somehow when I run the code, I keep getting "OutOfBoundaryException". I checked my code, and realized that when I instantiate a new instance of DataOutput, it creates all new data. So I tried to fix this by setting a constructor. However I still can't solve this matter. I know that I can put the ranker method into DataInput class, and problem will be easily solved however I really want to keep DataOutput class.

Thank you for your time.

PS: Exception is thrown on line 98, out.rrank[i]

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on? Could we see the full stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `students` field isn't set until the `save()` method is called. The value of `sNum` in `main` is then `0`.

Change the order in `main` to:

```
DataInput data = new DataInput();
data.save();// <--
int sNum = data.stu();
int[] sum = data.sum();
DataOutput out = new DataOutput(sNum, sum);
out.ranker();
```

Comment: Or better yet stop using sNum at all as it seens to be being used as a proxi for `sum.length`

Comment: @Johnbot. Didn't see that one! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that you initialize the rank[] before creating students, As soultion I suggest you to initialize after collection students/scores

```
public void init(int students, int[] sum){
      this.sNum = students;
        this.rrank = new int[sNum];
        this.sum = sum;
}
```

And update main()

```
  DataOutput out = new DataOutput();
    data.save();

    int sNum = data.stu();
    int[] sum = data.sum();
    out.init(sNum, sum);
    out.ranker();
```

Comment: @Johnbot solution is better